# Moderator Elections: tools for Community Managers

Tags: discussion, election, announcements

We have just wrapped up our project to make it easier for our [community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/) to run moderator elections for our Stack Exchange sites.

Between April and June, we released a number of administrative improvements that are mostly invisible to users, but that dramatically decrease the amount of time community managers spend performing routine tasks. The changes follow user-facing changes we launched earlier this year to the [questionnaire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362933/moderator-elections-new-questionnaire-ui) and [voting UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging).

### Generate the Question Collection post - Released April 30, 2021

For most elections, we ask the community to contribute questions they want the moderator candidates to answer in a [question collection Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection). Until now, community managers had to manually create these posts by copying and pasting standard copy into a new post.

Now CMs can simply click a button to automatically create a Meta post.

### Remind CMs to generate the questionnaire - Released June 5, 2021

When the nomination phase for an election begins, CMs need to generate the candidate questionnaire from the question collection post. If they forget, they receive a reminder email 30-90 minutes after the nomination phase begins.

### Automatically determine election winners - Released April 27, 2021

Prior to this release, CMs had to take a number of manual steps to determine which candidates won the election and to give them Moderator permissions. Now CMs just need to click a couple of buttons.

The system automatically creates an election via an API call to OpaVote, our third-party tabulation tool. The API returns the OpaVote URL and the winner(s) of the elections in a confirmation box. Selecting "Confirm winners" automatically bestows moderator diamonds on the winners.

### Automatically email new mods - Released June 1, 2021

When new mods are elected or appointed, they receive a welcome email with resources and instructions for how to be a mod. The CMs updated the email with new links and information.

### Automatically create election results Meta post - Released June 1, 2021

After winners have been determined, the CMs create a [Meta post announcing the winners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399609/2020-community-moderator-election-results) and thanking any moderators who may have stepped down. CMs can now do this by clicking a button. They see a preview screen where they can edit the contents of a Meta post that is prefilled with both the winning candidates and any retiring mods. When they are satisfied with the copy, then can click a button to publish the post.

### Automatically create a chat room - released May 18, 2021

CMs often create chat rooms so that candidates can discuss the election with voters. This is now a one-click process. The system creates the chat room and adds a link to the Election page, so that users can easily visit the chat room.

### Team Kudos

This project has been many months in the making. Wanted to acknowledge the hard work of various team members in making it happen.

- [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija?tab=profile) and [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat?tab=profile), CMs, for weighing in on requirements and testing.
- [Lisa Park](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/452001/lisa-park?tab=profile), designer, for designing the new voting UI and other user-facing improvements.
- [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear?tab=profile), [Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel?tab=profile), [Kyle Pollard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/718314/kyle-pollard?tab=profile) and [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis?tab=profile), software developers, for building out a wide swath of new features and functionality.

Comment: The **Team Kudos** section is a nice touch to the announcement.

Comment: "Selecting "Confirm winners" automatically bestows moderator diamonds on the winners." - don't the new mods have to accept the moderator agreement first before the diamond appears next to their username?