# A couple of typos in the moderator questionnaire

Tags: bug, election, wording, meta-tags

There are some minor bugs in the 2023 Moderator Election Questionnaire:
(e.g. at https://music.stackexchange.com/election)

Question 1 has a grammar mistake:

> 1. How would you deal with a user who <del>produced</del> [produces] a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Question 3 has a typo:

> 3. There is a new user that posts a few answers with the same link that may or may not be their own site or blog. Sometimes it seems like an appropriate resource, on other questions <del>it 'snot</del> [it's not] very relevant. One of the user's posts has been flagged as spam due to this. How do you approach handling this flag and the new user in general?

---

Also, meta-tags in answers (such as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)) are rendering in the colour scheme of regular tags.

Comment: This really ought to be on [Music Meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/), as it's specific to that site.

Comment: @Tetsujin Really? I thought they were generic questions.

Comment: The questions in part came from https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/2023-moderator-election-qa-question-collection [though the snot typo is a new invention]

Comment: Oh, yeah Q3 *was* a suggested question on the page (minus the snot).  But Q1 is one of the generic questions, you can see it in the SU election from a few years ago ([first image in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362933/moderator-elections-new-questionnaire-ui)).

Comment: Yeah, irritatingly, that's kind of 'one typo each' for main & music meta:\

Comment: Can you *describe* the grammar mistake? BTW, it *could* also be a true typo. "s" / "d" typos are very common, like many in the "a" / "s" / "e" / "d" / "r" cluster.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum It should be "produces" and "tends", or "produced" and "tendered", mixing up the tenses is the mistake.